# Need to stop Page validations while Implementing Logout

Tags: asp.net

while implementing Logout event Page validation events were raising in My form and It stops Firing  Logout Method

Need to stop page validation events when I call Logout Method using on ServerClick()

```
                        <li><a href="" runat="server" id="logout" class="trigger"  onserverclick="logout_ServerClick"><span>Logout</span></a></li>
```

My Code :

```
 protected void logout_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.Clear();
        Session.RemoveAll();

        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: use CausesValidation="False"

Comment: <asp:LinkButton id="logout" runat="server"
  Text="logout" CausesValidation="False">
</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: Thanks for ur response (Before Firing My Method Page starts validating and Gives me validation Messages)
And If All my Validations were valid Then My Logout Event is Firing

Comment: :) thanks dear if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CausesValidation="False"

```
 <asp:LinkButton id="logout" runat="server" Text="logout" CausesValidation="False"> </asp:LinkButton>
```